# dynamically allocated by new and delete in C++

Tags: c++

What is the value of q[2] and p[1][2] after each call to delete? And explain ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; int main() {
int **p = new int*[5]; int *q = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
q[i] = i;
} p[1] = q;
delete p; 
delete q;
delete [] q;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that attempting access to deleted objects causes undefined behavior?

Comment: Using the wrong `delete` is undefined behaviour as well. You're matching `new[]` with `delete` (at least for `p`; with `q`, you do it correctly, but only after using the wrong one).

Comment: @chris: I knew that was wrong, but I didn't know it was UB.

Comment: Has a new C standard been released or why did you add the C tag?

Answer (score 0):

This invokes **a lot** of undefined behaviour!

- `delete p`, whereas `p` is an *array*, thus it shall be `delete[] p`.
- ***Two*** consecutive deletes of `q`, one in array form another in non-array form. The correct one is the array form, **remove the other!**

Now, to answer the question. The value of `q[2]` is `2` (due to the `for` loop) until `q`'s deletion, when it invokes undefined behaviour due to the dereferencing of the dangling pointer `q`.

The value of `p[1][2]` is `2` (`p[1] == q`) until the deletion of `p`, when it invokes undefined behaviour due to the derefencing of the dangling pointer `p`.

BTW, SO is ***not*** the place to ask how to do your assignments!